# How can I configure htaccess for https-rewriting?

Tags: .htaccess, https, url-rewriting

I use https:// for some subdirectories (/login, /admininstration), for this I find some examples - but on the other hand I've to ensure, that all other pages redirect to http://.

Now, I send the user via links to https:// but when they leave the login-Area, they stay in https:// Mode.

I use now RewriteCond in standardconfiguration:

```
SetEnv APPLICATION_ENVIRONMENT show
RewriteEngine On

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} !^www.xxxseitexxx.de$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxseitexxx.de/$1 [L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d

RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [NC,L]

RewriteRule !\.(js|ico|gif|jpg|jpeg|png|css|inc|pdf|csv|zip|rm|mp3|swf)$ index.php
```

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this rule on top of other rules:

```
# force HTTP for not login or admininstration
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/admininstration|login/ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,R=302]

# force HTTPS for login or admininstration
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteRule ^(admininstration|login)/ https://%{HTTP_HOST}%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC,R=302]
```

Comment: Thanks, but sorry - it doesn't work.  The http-Part is running well, if you call a page with https now you get the http-Version.  But the https-part is not working: login gets to the http-Page (even if I call the https) and administration leads to the startpage. I should mention that we call /administration/start, not just /administration (but it should work for anything under /administration) and that the whole thing is generated as virtual path, generated by the framework.

Comment: If you're using a framework then there might be some rules already in place. Can you post your current .htaccess in your question.

Comment: What you see above is my full htaccess. Perhaps there is a collision to RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://www.xxxseitexxx.de/$1